# Expose my application data and processed data as Web Service

Tags: c#, service, soa

Assume I have a application that stores data,gets data and processes data and stores them in a database (which can be any).Say I want to expose my data as Web Services so that other systems can get the data they need for processing.

Q1.Is there any standards to follow? I can create Web Services in C#,so are the enough to say or claim that my app is SOA compliant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as "SOA Compliant".

Also, if you design your web service the way you've discussed, then I would argue that you are not doing SOA. SOA doesn't "expose data". SOA provides services. Don't "expose my data as Web Services", but rather provide services, which may happen to involve some of your data.

For instance, Amazon.com could provide a web service to just "expose their data". Alternatively, they could provide services like "List books by Author", "Purcahse book", "Add book to wish list", etc. Certainly some of those service operations are mostly data, but overall, a service is being provided, *using* the data.

Answer (score 0):

SOA isn't just web services, that's an implementation of web services. SOA is more of a vision than a technology.

I'd suggest [What is SOA](http://www.whatissoa.com/) as a good starting point for concepts and then you can decide on an implementation.